# Download one particular file from a large .zip file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Lets say I have a large .zip file in Google Drive with multiple images. Now I wish to download one particular file from this .zip file without downloading the entire .zip file. Is that possible? I checked there are apps like zip extractor, not sure it works. I tried but it takes forever to download the file. You may understand that the .zip file is in GBs.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in to Google Drive for working with ZIP files. You would need to use a Google Drive add-on. I'm sure there are several.

Of course, if you sync to your PC with the Google Drive sync tool, unless you've excluded that folder, the ZIP file is already on your hard drive.